# Как ограничить доступ к методам классов библиотеки для проекта?

Tags: java

Есть библиотека, в ней, к примеру, есть такой класс:

```
public class SimpleObject {
    private object;

    public void setObject(Object object) { ... }
    public Object getObject() { ... }
}
```

Рядом, в соседнем пакете, находится класс `ObjectHandler`, который принимает этот объект и, на основании результата метода `.getObject()`, что-то делает.

---

Нужно сделать так, чтобы пользователь, получив или создав объект `SimpleObject`, не мог использовать метод `.getObject()` (чтобы метод для пользователя был что-то вроде `private`), а класс `ObjectHandler` - мог и видел его.

Как это сделать?

---

Это нужно для того, чтобы не показывать пользователю лишние методы (и ему удобнее, и мне безопаснее). Сейчас для достижения этой цели приходится кидать объект и его обработчик в один пакет (что выглядит немного непонятно), а метод `get` делать доступным в пределах пакета.

Comment: То есть вам нужно, чтобы метод был доступен в одном пакете (не том же самом), но не был доступен в другом пакете?

Comment: вы хотите защититься от случайного использования? или от любого использования?

Comment: @Regent, ну.. Можно и так сказать.

Comment: @MikhailVaysman, любого.

Comment: @Regent, есть пакет проекта, а в нем куча подпакетов. Вот нужно чтобы метода одного подпакета были видны в других подпакетах, но не видны для всех, кто не находится в пакете проекта.

Comment: @RostislavDugin если для любого, то вряд ли есть решение лучше, чем  положить в один пакет. а если от случайного, то можно использовать интерфейс.

Comment: А почему хранение объекта и его обработчика в одном пакете выглядит непонятным?

Comment: Насколько я знаю, в Java нет такого, что из одного пакета (не того же самого) что-то видно, а из другого - нет.

Comment: Можно, конечно, в пакете, в котором находится класс `ObjectHandler`, создать класс `MySimpleObject extends SimpleObject`, в котором будут методы наподобие `protected Object getObject() { return super.getObject(); }`, но это уже чудеса костыльности. Да и пользователь, при желании, может такое же провернуть.

Comment: @Regent, непонятно, потому что обработчик - главный класс пакета, вокруг которого все крутится и он должен быть в корне, а объекты - в пакете `objects`. Люблю логическое разделение на пакеты. А то, что в Java такого нет - я хочу сомневаться (хотя книг я прочитал не мало), вдруг кто-то придумал.

Comment: В Java нет ни понятия "подпакет", ни `protected` (или `public`) c указанием конкретного пакета. Собственно, на этом моменте варианты межпакетного взаимодействия без всеобщего `public` и заканчиваются. А кроме костыльного `extends` класса есть ещё и вариант "пуститься во всякие тяжкие" и вызывать `protected`-метод с помощью рефлексии.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В Java нельзя "где-то сбоку" от `protected` или `public` (равно как и в начале файла) указать пакеты, в которых метод будет доступен. [В документации](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html) говорится только при каких модификаторах есть доступ в рамках пакета, а при каких - "во всём мире".
Также нет такого понятия как "подпакет" ("sub-package"). По этому поводу на enSO есть [хороший ответ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9279694/3432401).

Получается, что с помощью модификаторов доступа желаемого результата не добиться. В таком случае остаются такие варианты:

1. Оставить `SimpleObject` и `ObjectHandler` в одном пакете, если это оправданно или другие варианты не подходят.
2. Пересмотреть архитектуру классов. Например, возможно, что вместо `ObjectHandler` можно использовать суперкласс для `SimpleObject`, содержащий необходимый функционал.

Допустим, класс `SimpleObject` выглядит так:

```
package test2;
public class SimpleObject
{
    private Object object;
    public void setObject(Object object) { this.object = object; }
    protected Object getObject() { return object; }
}
```

"Костыльные" решения:

3. В пакете, в котором находится `ObjectHandler`, создать класс `MySimpleObject extends SimpleObject` и переопределить в нём нужные методы:

   ```
   package test3;
   import test2.SimpleObject;
   public class MySimpleObject extends SimpleObject
   {
       protected Object getObject() { return super.getObject(); }
   }
   ```

   После чего использовать `MySimpleObject` вместо `SimpleObject`:

   ```
   MySimpleObject mso = new MySimpleObject();
   mso.setObject("Str");
   System.out.println(mso.getObject());
   ```
4. "Пуститься во все тяжкие" и получать доступ к методу через рефлексию:

   ```
   SimpleObject so = new SimpleObject();
   so.setObject("Str");
   try
   {
       Method method = so.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("getObject");
       method.setAccessible(true);
       System.out.println(method.invoke(so));
   }
   catch (Exception e) { }
   ```

Comment: Эх... Все так, как я и думал (но, честно говоря, костыльных решений Вы придумали больше, мне про рефлексию даже ничего бы в голову не пришло :)). Но я все же придумал решения (в рамках проекта, а не вопроса): сделаю `Builder` с видимыми в рамках проекта методами `get`, а потом создам объект с логикой. Ну.... Может звучит не очень понятно, потом проект покажу :).

Answer (score 1):

От "глупостей" "пользователей" защититься нельзя.
Если Ваш `SimpleObject` относится к уровню сущностей (`@Entity`), то все его getters & setters должны быть `public`. Это правильно и логично. И нет ничего плохого в том, что кто-то будет создавать и полноценно использовать Вашу сущность `SimpleObject`.

Но, если `SimpleObject` — это некий API-метод, то действительно нужно `.getObject()` защитить от "пользователя", то есть контролировать защиту от получения некорректного значения или вызова `.getObject()` в неподходящий момент по логике вашего проекта.

В таком случае, я рекомендую оставить модификатор видимости `public getObject()`, но защититься от неправильного использования через `Exception`.

Создайте свой `Exception` или используйте существующий. Например:

```
public class MyLogicalException extends Exception {
    public MyLogicalException(String message) {
        super(message);
    }
}
```

И объявите, что метод `getObject()` может выбрасывать исключение `MyLogicalException` при определенных обстоятельствах. Например:

```
public Object getObject() throws MyLogicalException {
    if (object == null) {
        throw new MyLogicalException("object не может быть пустым!");
    } else {
        return object;
    }
}
```

Comment: Хм, а действительно интересный вариант! Так же можно (если нужно для всех методов), выполнять проверку интерцептором.